Implicit excel @ in openxlsx unique formula in R
I'm trying to produce a table that checks two different table columns, stacks them together to check unique values. When I write this formula manually in excel, it works as expected, but when produced using openxlsx, it automatically adds an @ to the formula, which breaks it. I want it to return a list, not just one cell.
Anyway around this? I could manually remove the @ symbol, but I need to produce 15 files in this format each month, so I don't want to have the manual step each time. The code is also set up so that it would be very difficult/impossible to use a loaded template workbook (as it relies on the tables that are being created in the script).
Code:
  # Write formulae for unique sublocations and then the checks
  writeFormula(wb, "Checks",
               "UNIQUE(VSTACK(newreferencefile[sublocation_code], newrosterreferencefile[sublocation_code]))",
               startCol = 1, startRow = 4)

Output in excel:
=@UNIQUE(VSTACK(newreferencefile[sublocation_code], newrosterreferencefile[sublocation_code]))

Did you try with a more standard/easy formula first (e.g. the SUM or AVERAGE function) if tehse one work? If so, I guess it might be related to the newreferencefile[sublocation_code], newrosterreferencefile[sublocation_code] part? Is this part refering to an R data object? This won't work because the formula expects a reference to the Excel sheet/positions.

The references are exceltablename[columnname], so it's the same formula as with a manual set up. By manually removing the @ in the output, it works as expected so it's literally just the implicit @ that's causing the headaches

It is giving an error because the formula does not return a single value for the cell, but a list of values. And this is not currently supported. What you can do is add the argument "array = TRUE" to remove the @ but the formula will appear between {}
writeFormula(wb, "Checks",
             "UNIQUE(VSTACK(newreferencefile[sublocation_code], newrosterreferencefile[sublocation_code]))",
             startCol = 1, startRow = 4, array = TRUE)

If you double click in col 1 and row 4 (in the excel) and hit enter, it works.

Thank you - I have set it up in that way using openxlsx2 now, so have decided to accept the manual step at the end to automatically populate the formula.

Yeah, openxlsx2 doesn't solve the problem completely either. Handling Excel from R can be complex due to permissions and other things. Maybe you could generate the files and then apply a macro to all of them. I hope I have helped.

As stated by Valentina, the formula result spans multiple cells. In addition =UNIQUE() is what OOXML calls a future function (not part of the original standard, but developed for a later release of Excel).
What you can do is something like this in openxlsx2, but this is basically using the base R function unique() to determine the length of cells required by =UNIQUE(). Also if you want to select unique characters, be aware that x and X are identical for =UNIQUE(), you might want to use openxlsx2:::distinct() in this case).
library(openxlsx2)
wb <- wb_workbook()$add_worksheet()$
  add_data(x = cars)$
  add_data(dims = "D1", x = "Unique Values of Speed")$
  add_formula(
    dims = wb_dims(x = unique(cars$speed), from_col = "D", from_row = 2),
    x = paste0("_xlfn.UNIQUE(", wb_dims(x = cars, cols = "speed"), ")"),
    array = TRUE
  )
if (interactive()) wb$open()

Example from here

Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, while that would work to display the current list of unique values the aim is to have it linked to a column in an Excel Table, so that the workbook can be used, and the list of unique sublocation codes will keep updating as the user makes changes.
